# Not receiving 'paste:' action from UITextField's canPerformAction:withSender

Tags: ios5, uitextfield

I want to disable the 'Paste' option for a UITextField and in my UITextField's delegate class, I am providing an implementation for:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

`NSObject(UIResponderStandardEditActions)` defines the following actions and I get all of them sent to me in `canPerformAction` except `paste:`

```
@interface NSObject(UIResponderStandardEditActions)   // these methods are not implemented in NSObject

- (void)cut:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
- (void)copy:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
- (void)paste:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
- (void)select:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
- (void)selectAll:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
- (void)delete:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_2);
- (void)makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
- (void)makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:(id)sender __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);

@end
```

Right now, anytime the clipboard has content in it and I give focus to a UITextField, I see the 'paste' menu displayed.

Is there something else I should be doing to receive the paste message?

Comment: You should override canPerformAction in a UITextField subclass

Comment: I don't have a subclass of UITextField. Instead, I have a delegate class set for the UITextField where I'm dealing with the 'canPerformAction'. Is a delegate not adequate?

Comment: No the canPerformAction is called on the UITextField itself, not on the delegate

Answer (score 1):

create a subclass of `UITextField` and override the `canPerform` there, the `paste:` action is called on the `UITextField`, and not on the `delegate`